# ajax is not working on different system

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

My ajax code is working on my system, but not working on different system. I'm using ajax on mousehover.

```
<div class="production"> <a href="production.html" onclick="autoProd();" onmouseover="autoProd();" onmouseout="homepage();">production</a> </div>
```

and the script is..

```
<script>
function getXML(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
        return ajax;
    }
    else{
        var ajax=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        return ajax;
    }

}
function autoProd(){

        var ajax=getXML();

    /*var name=document.getElementById('sugg').value;*/
    var url="../ajax/production.html";

        ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200)
                document.getElementById('layer1').innerHTML=ajax.responseText;

        }
        ajax.open("get",url,true);
        ajax.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: use jQuery or something similiar. the pain with browser differences will not cease.

Comment: Why do you say it "doesn't work"?  What does it not do?

Comment: If it's a JS error, look in the error console (Firebug for Firefox/Chrome)

Comment: does `../ajax/production.html` exist on the new system? is it at the same location?

Comment: different system means on different desktop or laptop. and also not working on server

Comment: onmouseover it is not loading ajax.

Comment: add a handler to respond to the ajax fail and see what the error message is. check a traffic monitoring tool (e.g. fiddler) to see if the request is even going out and what the server responds with.

Comment: firebug does not disply any error.but error count increasing in firebug. yes "../ajax/production.html" existing on new system.

Comment: Which browsers work, and which don't?

Comment: it is working on localhost of my laptop. but while i m using it on my friend laptop, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
function getXML(){
    try {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        return ajax;

    } catch (error1) {
        try { 
            var ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            return ajax;

        } catch (error2) {
            try {
                var ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                return ajax;

            } catch (error3) {
                return null;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I m new to this and unable to handle this. should i change the code or write it as it is, means(error1...)?

Comment: You can write is at it is. error1 is just name, we are not using it.